# Are timestamps available for system log entries on OS X?

Tags: macos, boot, logging, timestamp

Busy troubleshooting the cause of a slow startup sequence on OS X.

It hangs for about 10 minutes at one point, and thus the ability to see where this occurs, would be super useful.

Comment: Not sure how, but the Console app has a menu option to show milliseconds. If you do `tail -f /var/log/system.log` in Terminal you get similar to default Console display (seconds) and the actual log file only shows in seconds!?

Comment: Cool, thanks john.
  
I was using `dmesg` in particular which doesn't give timestamps but also not sure how all the logging techniques relate to one another `syslog`, `dmesg`, ASL and where they are physically stored.

Been trying to piece it together using Google searches, but it's rather tricky. :/

Comment: Sounds like you know more than I!

Comment: The answer to this post is relevant: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/302630/where-to-see-kernel-startup-messages-after-boot